# Prove that $(a+b)^p$ = $a^p+b^p \bmod p$ for any prime $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that  $(a+b)^p$ = $a^p+b^p \bmod p$ for any prime $p$ (and integers $a,b$)

The given hint is use part A and the binomial theorem:

I have proven part A, which is $ 0 < i < p$ then $p$ divides $p \choose i$.

I am however, at a loss as to how to proceed from here.

Comment: Hint: By the binomial theorem, $(a+b)^p=a^p+\binom{p}{1}a^{p-1}b+\binom{p}{2}a^{p-2}b^2+\cdots +\binom{p}{p-1}ab^{p-1}+b^p$.

Comment: Yeah, I have it here written as a summation. But I can't see how to apply it, I think the (mod p) is throwing me off.

Comment: By Part A, all the terms except the first and the last are congruent to $0$ modulo $p$. So, modulo $p$, you are adding a bunch of $0$'s to $a^p+b^p$.